# Google Maps Datums - Australia

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-markers

Does anyone know where I can find out what Datum version Google maps is using?

If it is using GDA94, is it possible to force GDA2020 via the API?

https://www.propertyandlandtitles.vic.gov.au/surveying/geodetic-survey/geocentric-datum-of-australia

http://www.ga.gov.au/scientific-topics/positioning-navigation/geodesy/datums-projections/gda2020

https://www.icsm.gov.au/gda2020

Answer (score 1):

per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/coordinates): Google uses the World Geodetic System WGS84 standard

> **Map and Tile Coordinates**
> The Maps JavaScript API uses the following coordinate systems:
>
> - Latitude and longitude values, which reference a point on the world uniquely. (Google uses the World Geodetic System WGS84 standard.)

Comment: What Map Grid of Australia projection does Google use? MGA94 or MGA2020

Comment: It doesn't use anything special for Australia, it uses WGS84 for the whole world.

Comment: Have been looking over software integrations where it references in docs both WGS84 and the Map Grid of Australia MGA94.

Rather confused what MGA is, my understanding MGA is the map projection and WGS is the coordinate system that sits ontop.

Is WGS cover both coordinates and a map grids?